# Bootstrap dropdowns not working as asp include files

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, ssi

I am using server side includes for my navigation bar on my website. The bootstrap navigation bar works just fine in its own file: the dropdown opens and closes on mobile, but once I include it on the page I want it on (  ), the dropdown only will dropdown and won't go back up.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, or if anyone can figure out what is going wrong.

Here is the code to just the navigation bar that works correctly by itself.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="../_css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.asp">O<span>NE</span> HEALTH <small>Nebraska One Health Resource Portal</small></a>

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>      
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right collapse navbar-collapse">

        <li><a href="/health-resources.asp">Health Resources</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="/around-the-globe.asp">Around the Globe</a></li>

        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right search" role="search">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

    </ul>  
</div>
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Then I here is where I try and include the file, where the dropdowns no longer work....

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="../_css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- NAVIGATION -->
<!--#include virtual="/navigation/navigation.asp" -->

     <div class="index-main">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <h1 style="text-align: center">One Health</h1>
        <h4 style="text-align: center; line-height: 35px; font-weight: 300">One Health is a comprehensive approach to public health which recognizes that the health of the environment, animals (wild and domestic), and humans are interconnected. To have long-term success against diseases, we have to address all three areas because diseases in one group frequently spill over and affect the others. The Nebraska One Health Program is a grant-funded program to network, research, and educate producers, pest control operators, educators, public health officals, and other interested parties about addressing diseases in nature that affect humans and their animals.</h4>
</div>
</div>
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: where is your dropdown button in this?

Comment: <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

Comment: is it working in mobile?

Comment: nope, the asp file for just the navigation works, but when I include it into my index page it does not work properly. It will drop down, but it will not drop back up.

Answer (score 0):

download the files and include them to your html page locally and check once.

Comment: You mean don't do include files? Just put it on my page? I guess I'm just trying to figure out if bootstrap dropdowns are supported as .asp server side includes and if so, how do I get it working properly